# MATLAB image processing installed, but imhist doesn't work

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, video-processing

I was trying to get a histogram for an image (uint8, Using MATLAB R2016a), but am getting the following message:

```
Undefined function or variable 'imhist'.
```

I have double checked, and my image processing toolbox is installed (as seen in the attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dyds.jpg)). I have looked around for quite a while, but still couldn't spot the problem.

Comment: What does your path preference state?  Is the toolbox listed there?

Comment: not sure what do you mean - under Set Path?

Comment: Hang on, I'll post an answer so you can see a screenshot of what I mean.

Comment: Type `ver` at the command line. That should show all the installed toolboxes... If it's not there I would first make sure you have a licence and then run the installer again. The installer should install all toolboxes for which you have a licence.

Comment: There's a note in the [add-on manager documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/manage-your-add-ons.html) that mentions this could be a problem if you change your installation folder as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the MATLAB path to make sure the toolbox is listed there.

1. Through the GUI

   Access **Set Path** through the GUI's top menubar, see screenshot:

   [image: Set path]

   A dialog with a list of the different toolboxes that are on your path will popup next.  You can add the toolbox directly if it is not already there.
2. Through the command window.

   To see your current list of paths that are accessible, type:

   ```
   path
   ```

   If you know the pathname where the toolbox is, then you can add it directly like this:

   ```
   toolboxPath = '/your/paths/toolbox/image';
   addpath(genpath(toolboxPath));
   ```

Comment: Thank you. Had some trouble finding the right path, but it was under toolbox/images, rather than toolbox/matlab/images,

Comment: For sure, and I'll update the path in my answer in case anyone else comes along with the same issue.  Do you want to accept this answer?

Comment: Yup thats great

Comment: Cool.  You may need to click Accept still; it's not showing up here.  Regardless, I'm glad you got things working.  Good luck with the image processing!